# PhoneGap/Cordova 3 standard client side database

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

The PhoneGap documentation discusses two different options for client side data storage (Web Storage/Web SQL Database), but neither supports all of the platforms listed as supported PhoneGap platforms.

Is there a plugin available that supports the remaining platforms (Bada/Symbian)?

Of the 2 options that are available; is one more likely than the other to have continue future support, or is there a plugin that wraps the 2 so that there is a single unified API for client side data storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think it is exist now. As local storage or Web SQL is part of HTML5 API. It depends on browser engine.
2. I use [persistencejs](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs) for storage abstraction to unify API call. You can use 'driver' for each storage, please refer to [this](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs#setting-up). You can may consider [jaydata](http://jaydata.org/), [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) by creator of Phonegap, or [breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/)

Comment: Thanks.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but for all the searching I've done I haven't been able to turn anything else up either :(